# Google maps setting Default UI method

Tags: google-maps

So I know you can set the DefaultDisableUI in map options to be true or false. But I didn't know if it was possible for example to do map.SetDefaultUI(true) or false as its possible for map.setZoom. I want this because I do not want the default UI to be always displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after creating the map, you can do

```
map.setOptions({
    disableDefaultUI: true
});
```

to disable the default UI.